# update DataGridView after search database

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I use TableAdapter (DataSetTools) to communicate with my database. I have a datagridview and I want to fill it by result of a search query. This is my code:

myDataSet = name of dataset that I created with dataset tools.

Test = name of my table in database.

```
myDataSetTableAdapters.TestTableAdapter myTableAdapter = new myDataSetTableAdapters.TestTableAdapter();
myDataSet.TestDataTable dt =myTableAdapter .Search(txtSearch.Text);
TestBindingSource.EndEdit();
TITable.Fill(dt);
testDataGridView.Update();
testDataGridView.Refresh();
```

The problem is that I don't see any changes in datagridview.

Comment: Chek https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/18a9762e-ac67-48a7-a372-55307fe344f3/how-do-you-refresh-data-bound-to-a-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good (generic) cample which you should be able to follow pretty easily.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection ;
            SqlCommand command ;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataView dv ;
            string sql = null;
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            sql = "Select * from product";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds, "Update");
                adapter.Dispose();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();

                dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0], "", "Product_Name", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
                int index = dv.Find("PRODUCT5");

                if (index == -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show ("Product not found");
                }
                else
                {
                    dv[index]["Product_Name"] = "Product11";
                    MessageBox.Show("Product Updated !");
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, check out this example.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCommand sCommand;
        SqlDataAdapter sAdapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder sBuilder;
        DataSet sDs;
        DataTable sTable;        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Stores";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
            sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
            sDs = new DataSet();
            sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores");
            sTable = sDs.Tables["Stores"];
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["Stores"];
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            save_btn.Enabled = false;
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }

        private void new_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
            save_btn.Enabled = true;
            new_btn.Enabled = false;
            delete_btn.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void delete_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                sAdapter.Update(sTable);
            }
        }

        private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sAdapter.Update(sTable);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            save_btn.Enabled = false;
            new_btn.Enabled = true;
            delete_btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You will find MANY other examples using the link below.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-database-operations.htm